# Confused about angular with php

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, angular-material

I fairly new to angular and saving data to the db and then retrieving it. I am working with Angular Material as one of my dependencies.

In a first step I was successfull in creating a user (saving to db) and then retrieving it via a ng-repeat on a list. And lastly doing a delete of a user.

Now i want to do exactly the same but then for creating a task with some more input fields in my form. Here I am encountering several issues:

1. my ng-repeat does not update automatically (i have a work around in case of digest recycle)
2. the delete does not work although in my console it says that it did (in my table the record is still showing. 100% sure the php code is correct, mainly just a copy paste from the CRUD of user)

The form is in a dialog box (md-dialog -> angular material) (the same was for creating a user)

HTML code:

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div class="tile contentEditorBox" ng-dblclick="showPopUp($event)" ce-drag ce-resize ng-repeat="task in taskInfo"
      style="top: {{ gridSizeNG.y * item.row }}px; left: {{ gridSizeNG.x * item.column }}px; width: {{ gridSizeNG.x * item.width }}px; "
      ng-data-id="{{ task.id }}" ng-init="snapInit()">
        <div class="txtWrapperTile">
        <div class="containerTxt">
          <div class="taskName">
             <h5> {{ task.task_name }} </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="taskProjectClient">
            <!-- <p class="pPC"> {{ task.task_project_client_name}} </p> -->
             <p class="pPC"> {{ task.id_Location }} </p> 
          </div>
        </div><!-- end containerTxt -->
        </div><!-- end txtWrapperTile -->
      </div>         
</body>
```

Code for the dialog box -> dialog1.tmpl.html

```
<md-dialog aria-label="">
  <form ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <md-input-container md-no-float="">
          <input class="customInput" placeholder="Name this task..." name="task_name" ng-model="task_name">
        </md-input-container>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="closeDialog()">
          <md-icon md-svg-src="images/ic_close_24px.svg" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-dialog-content>
      <div id="containerForm">
          <div layout="row">
              <div class="labelPosition">
                <md-select-label>Project type</md-select-label>
              </div>
              <div id="containerSelectListProjectType">
                <md-select ng-model="task_project_type" name="project_type" placeholder="Choose a project type" id="containerProjectType">
                <md-option ng-model="selected_task_project_type" ng-repeat="projecttype in projectTypeInfo" ng-value="{{projecttype.id_ProjectType}}">{{projecttype.project_type}}</md-option>
              </md-select>
              </div>

          </div>

          <br/>

          <div layout="row">
            <div class="labelPosition">
              <md-select-label>Location</md-select-label>
            </div>
            <div id="containerSelectListLocation">
               <md-select ng-model="task_location" name="location" placeholder="Choose your location">
                <md-option ng-repeat="location in locationInfo" ng-value="{{location.id_Location}}">{{location.location}}</md-option>
              </md-select>
            </div>
          </div>  

          <br/>

          <div layout="row">
            <div class="labelPositionET">
              <md-select-label>Estimate time</md-select-label>
            </div>
            <div id="containerEstimateTime">
                <md-input-container md-no-float="">
                    <input name="estimate_time" placeholder="0 hours" ng-model="task_estimate_time">
                </md-input-container>
            </div>    
          </div>  

          <br/>

          <div layout="row">
            <div class="labelPositionCP">
              <md-select-label>Client/Project</md-select-label>
            </div>  
            <div id="containerClientProject">
                <md-input-container md-no-float="">
                    <input name="project_client_name" placeholder="Project/Client name" ng-model="task_project_client_name">
                </md-input-container>
            </div>
          </div> 

          <br />

          <div layout="row" ng-show="showUrl">
            <div class="labelPosition">
              <md-select-label>Url</md-select-label>
            </div>  
            <div id="containerUrl">
                <md-input-container md-no-float="">
                    <input name="url" placeholder="Url" ng-model="task_url">
                </md-input-container>
            </div>
          </div> 

          <br />

          <div layout="row" ng-show="showResourceLink">
            <div class="labelPosition">
              <md-select-label>Resource link</md-select-label>
            </div>  
            <div id="containerResourceLink">
                <md-input-container md-no-float="">
                    <input name="resource_link" placeholder="Resource link" ng-model="task_resource_link">
                </md-input-container>
            </div>
          </div> 

          <br />

          <div layout="row" ng-show="showNotes">
            <div class="labelPosition">
              <md-select-label>Note's</md-select-label>
            </div>  
            <div id="containerNotes">
                <md-input-container md-no-float="">
                  <textarea ng-model="task_notes" ng-model="task_notes" placeholder="Note's" columns="1" md-maxlength="150"></textarea>
                </md-input-container>
            </div>
          </div> 

          <div layout="row">
            <input type="text" id="coord_x" name="coordinate_x" value="" ng-model="task_coordinate_x" >
            <input type="text" id="coord_y" name="coordinate_y" value="" ng-model="task_coordinate_y">
          </div>

      </div>
    </md-dialog-content>
    <div class="md-actions" layout="row">
      <md-button  class="md-primary" ng-click="delete_task(task.id)">Delete</md-button>

      <md-button  class="md-primary" ng-click="showUrl = ! showUrl">Url</md-button>

      <md-button  class="md-primary" ng-click="showResourceLink = ! showResourceLink">Resource link</md-button>

      <md-button  class="md-primary" ng-click="showNotes = ! showNotes">Note's</md-button>

      <md-button  class="md-primary" ng-click="edit_task()">Edit</md-button>  

      <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-primary">Cancel</md-button>

      <md-button ng-click="save_task(); closeDialog()" class="md-primary">Save</md-button>
    </div>
  </form>
</md-dialog>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {

      var resultLocalStorageCoordX = document.getElementById("coord_x");
      resultLocalStorageCoordX.value = localStorage.getItem("coordinateX");
      console.log(resultLocalStorageCoordX);
      var coordX = $('#coord_x').val();
      console.log('Coord X (inputfield): ' + coordX);

      var resultLocalStorageCoordY = document.getElementById("coord_y");
      resultLocalStorageCoordY.value = localStorage.getItem("coordinateY");
      console.log(resultLocalStorageCoordY);
      var coordY= $('#coord_y').val();
      console.log('Coord Y (inputfield): ' + coordY);

  });
</script>
```

Code in my app.js file. There is a lot more code in my app.js file for dragging, dropping, resizing, snapping to grid, creating grid lines. But for the purpose of this question I left the code out.

```
(function() {
    var contentEditor = angular.module("DragDrop", ['ngMaterial']);    
    contentEditor.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog, $http){
        $scope.taskInfo = [];

        var getTaskFunction = function(successFn, errorFn) 
        { 
              // original implementation of $scope.get_user but with success & error used which as passed in as parameter. 
              $http.get('db.php?action=get_Task_Info') // call the server 

              .success(function(data) { // upon success 
                  successFn(data); 
                  console.log("Retrieved task data from server");
              }) 
              .error(errorFn || function() { 
                  console.log("Error in retrieving data from server");
              }) // process failure  
          };

          this.reloadTaskList = function() {
          getTaskFunction(       
              /* success function */ 
              function(data) { 
                  //debugger; 
                  $scope.taskInfo = data; 
              }, 
              /* error function */ 
              function() 
              { 
                console.log("Server load failed"); 
              }
            ) 
        };

        // load list on startup
        this.reloadTaskList();

        /** function to add details for a task in mysql referecing php **/
        $scope.save_task = function() {
            $http.post('db.php?action=add_task', 
                {
                    'task_name'                  : $scope.task_name, 
                    'id_ProjectType'             : $scope.task_project_type, 
                    'id_Location'                : $scope.task_location, 
                    'task_estimate_time'         : $scope.task_estimate_time, 
                    'task_project_client_name'   : $scope.task_project_client_name,
                    'task_url'                   : $scope.task_url,
                    'task_resource_link'         : $scope.task_resource_link,
                    'task_notes'                 : $scope.task_notes,
                    'task_coordinate_x'          : $scope.task_coordinate_x,
                    'task_coordinate_y'          : $scope.task_coordinate_y
                }
            )

            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //$scope.userInfo.push(data);
                //$scope.get_task(); //this will fetch latest record from DB
                getTaskFunction( 
                  /* success function */ 
                  function(data) { 
                      $scope.taskInfo = data; 
                      console.log("The tasks have been reloaded");
                  }, 
                  /* error function */ 
                  function() 
                  { 
                      console.log("Server load failed"); 
                  } 
                );
                console.log("The task has been added successfully to the DB");
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Failed to add the task to DB");
            });
        }

        //Populating select list with data from DB for project type
        $scope.getProjectTypeFunction = function() {
            $http.get('db.php?action=get_ProjectType_Info').success(function(data)
            { 
                $scope.projectTypeInfo = data;   
                console.log("Retrieved data (project type) from the server"); 
                //console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
            {
                console.log("Error in retrieving data from server");
            });
        }

       $scope.getProjectTypeFunction(); //-- call the function that calls $http

       //Populating select list with data from DB for location
        $scope.getLocationFunction = function() {
            $http.get('db.php?action=get_Location_Info').success(function(data)
            { 
                $scope.locationInfo = data;   
                console.log("Retrieved data (location) from the server"); 
                //console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
            {
                console.log("Error in retrieving data from server");
            });
        }

        $scope.getLocationFunction(); //-- call the function that calls $http
        $scope.showPopUp= function(ev) {
            $mdDialog.show({
              controller: DialogController,
              templateUrl: 'dialog1.tmpl.html',
              parent: angular.element(document.body),
              targetEvent: ev,
            })

            function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
                $scope.closeDialog = function() {
                    var mainApp = angular.element(document.body).controller();  
                    $mdDialog.hide();

                }

            }
        }

        /** function to delete a task from list referencing php **/
        $scope.delete_task = function(index) {  
        $http.post('db.php?action=delete_task', 
            {
                'task_index' : index
            }
        )      
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {    
            // here we also replace how to get the user
            getTaskFunction( 
                /* success function */ 
                function(data) { 
                    $scope.taskInfo = data; 
                   console.log("The tasks have been reloaded (in the delete function)");
                }, 
                /* error function */ 
                function() 
                { 
                    alert("Server load failed (in the delete function)"); 
                } 
            );
            console.log('Deletion was succesfull');
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           console.log("You were NOT succesfull in deleting a task"); 
        });
    }

    })
})();
```

PHP code:

```
<?php 
    include('config.php');

    switch($_GET['action'])  {
        case 'get_ProjectType_Info' :
            get_ProjectType_Info(); 
            break;
        case 'add_task' :
            add_task(); 
            break;
        case 'get_Location_Info' :
            get_Location_Info(); 
            break;
        case 'get_Task_Info' :
            get_Task_Info(); 
            break; 
        case 'delete_task' :
            delete_task(); 
            break; 
    }

    /**  Function to data from tblProjectType **/
    function get_ProjectType_Info(){
        $qry = mysql_query('SELECT * from tblProjectType');

        $data = array();
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
        {
            $data[] = array(
                        "id_ProjectType"    => $rows['id_ProjectType'],
                        "project_type"      => $rows['project_type']
                        );
        }

        print_r(json_encode($data));
        //return json_encode($data);
    }

    /**  Function to data from tblLocation **/
    function get_Location_Info(){
        $qry = mysql_query('SELECT * from tblLocation');

        $data = array();
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
        {
            $data[] = array(
                        "id_Location"   => $rows['id_Location'],
                        "location"      => $rows['location']
                        );
        }

        print_r(json_encode($data));
        //return json_encode($data);
    }


    /**  Function to add a task to db **/
    function add_task() {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); 
        $task_name                    = $data->task_name; 
        $task_project_type            = $data->id_ProjectType;  
        $task_location                = $data->id_Location;  
        $task_estimate_time           = $data->task_estimate_time;
        $task_project_client_name     = $data->task_project_client_name;
        $task_url                     = $data->task_url;
        $task_resource_link           = $data->task_resource_link;
        $task_notes                   = $data->task_notes;
        $task_coordinate_x            = $data->task_coordinate_x;
        $task_coordinate_y            = $data->task_coordinate_y;

        print_r($data);

        $qry = 'INSERT INTO tblTask(task_name, id_ProjectType, id_Location, task_estimate_time, task_project_client_name, task_url, task_resource_link, task_notes, task_coordinate_x, task_coordinate_y) 
                VALUES ("' 
                . $task_name . '","' 
                . $task_project_type . '","' 
                . $task_location . '","' 
                . $task_estimate_time . '","'
                . $task_project_client_name . '","' 
                . $task_url . '","'
                . $task_resource_link . '","' 
                . $task_notes . '","' 
                . $task_coordinate_x . '","' 
                . $task_coordinate_y .'")';

        /*$qry = 'INSERT INTO tblTask(task_coordinate_x, task_coordinate_y) 
                VALUES ("' . $task_coordinate_x . '","' . $task_coordinate_y .'")';
*/
        echo ($qry);

        $qry_res = mysql_query($qry);
        if ($qry_res) {
            $arr = array('msg' => "Task added successfully!!!", 'error' => '');
            $jsn = json_encode($arr);
            // print_r($jsn);
        } 
        else {
            $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Error in inserting record');
            $jsn = json_encode($arr);
            // print_r($jsn);
        }
    }

    /**  Function to get a task info   **/
    function get_Task_Info() {    
        /*$qryGet = mysql_query('SELECT * from tblTask');*/

        $qryGet = mysql_query('Select *, tblLocation.location from tblTask INNER JOIN tblLocation on tblTask.id_Location=tblLocation.id_Location');

        /*echo ($qryGet);*/

        $data = array();
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qryGet))
        {
            $data[] = array(
                        "id"                        => $rows['id'],
                        "task_name"                 => $rows['task_name'],
                        "task_project_type"         => $rows['id_ProjectType'],
                        "task_location"             => $rows['id_Location'],
                        "task_estimate_time"        => $rows['task_estimate_time'],
                        "task_project_client_name"  => $rows['task_project_client_name'],
                        "task_url"                  => $rows['task_url'],
                        "task_resource_link"        => $rows['task_resource_link'],
                        "task_notes"                => $rows['task_notes']
                        );
        }

        print_r(json_encode($data));
        //return json_encode($data);  
    }

    /**  Function to delete a task   **/
    function delete_task() {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));     
        $index = $data->task_index;     
        //print_r($data);
        $del = mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblTask WHERE id = ".$index);
        if($del)
        return true;
        return false;     
    }   
?>
```

So basically i need help with:

1. the delete function
2. ng-repeat not updating automatically

I hope someone can really help me out.

Comment: Did you console log the data you get in delete_task? Do you get updated data?